# wxPython Sizer set fixed height for panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm very new to wxPython and am just learning how to use sizers. I've successfully created a panel that seems to be aligned correctly, however i want to place a new panel directly underneath it, and am running into problems there. I want this first panel with a green background to have a fixed height, but the green background is filling the entire frame, even though the panel seems to have its contents aligned how i want inside of it.  Thanks for any help.

Here is a picture with the frame maximized to fill my window:

[image]

This is just a single panel. The contents of the panel are aligned correctly along the top, however i want the panel to stop just below those widgets so i can start a new panel. So the green color shouldnt fill the whole window, as i have set the bg for this frame to be green. the green should stop just below the widgets, then i want to add another frame.

Here is my complete code:

```
import time
import os
import gc
import wx
import wx.grid

# wxpython app
# read ss from files or live version
class Wx_app(wx.App):

    # __init__ gets called first when any class is initialized
    def __init__(self):

    # intiialize the App window
    super().__init__(clearSigInt=True)

    # don't set size of the frame, just position. let 
    # sizers do the sizing?
    self.frame = MyFrame(None, pos=(10,10))

# frame class (wx python wind)
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # ini the frame and show it
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # main sizer, will contain all of the other sizers
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # FONTS
        # font to use for the panel in labels, text ctrls, etc
        txt_font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        # font to use for buttons is slightly small than txt_font
        but_font = wx.Font(15, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)

        # PANEL 1
        # first panel is at the top, contains manual pick area plus msg area
        self.pick_area_panel = PickAreaPanel(self, txt_font, but_font)
        self.main_sizer.Fit(self.pick_area_panel)


        # show the frame with panel
        self.Show(True)

# panel class
class PickAreaPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, txt_font, but_font):

        # ini
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        # set background colour for panel
        self.SetBackgroundColour("Green")

        # create the sizer for this panel.
        # stuff is organized horizontally left to right
        self.panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # NOTE: By setting width to -1, we tell to go with sizer, and height to 100
        # sets a fixed height
        pick_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Confirm Pick R1 P1: ", size=(240, 25))
        pick_label.SetBackgroundColour("Red")
        pick_label.SetFont(txt_font)

        # input textctrl for the manual pick
        pick_input = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(320, 25))
        pick_input.SetFont(txt_font)

        # button to confirm manual pick
        pick_confirm_but = wx.Button(self, -1, size=(150, 25))
        pick_confirm_but.SetLabel("Confirm")
        pick_confirm_but.SetFont(but_font)

        # PROG MSG AREA
        # no fixed size, fills rest of panel after previous elements
        # need a nested sizer so can control borders
        # and give it a left borcer thats different from its top border
        prog_msg_area_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        prog_msg_area = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "MSG MSG MSG", size=(-1, 25), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        prog_msg_area.SetBackgroundColour("White")
        prog_msg_area.SetFont(txt_font)
        prog_msg_area_sizer.Add(prog_msg_area, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, border=0)

        # add elements to panel sizer
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_label, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, border=3)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_input, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_confirm_but, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # prog msg area has its own horiz sizer so can set a left border diff from top border 
        self.panel_sizer.Add(prog_msg_area_sizer, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        # add panel sizer to the main sizer
        # set proporition to 0 so height of panel doesnt change when height of frame changes
        # adds a border around the entire panel
        parent.main_sizer.Add(self.panel_sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=15)

        # set panel to use the main sizer
        # not sure exactly how this works....
        self.SetSizer(parent.main_sizer)

wx_app = Wx_app()       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

EDITED PROGRAM WITH SUGGESTED CHANGES

```
import time
import os
import gc
import wx
import wx.grid

class Wx_app(wx.App):

    def __init__(self):

    super().__init__(clearSigInt=True)

    self.frame = MyFrame(None, pos=(10,10))

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        txt_font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        but_font = wx.Font(15, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)

        self.pick_area_panel = PickAreaPanel(self, txt_font, but_font)

        # *******ADDED:
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)

        self.Show(True)

# panel class
class PickAreaPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, txt_font, but_font):

        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.SetBackgroundColour("Green")

        self.panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        pick_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Confirm Pick R1 P1: ", size=(240, 25))
        pick_label.SetBackgroundColour("Red")
        pick_label.SetFont(txt_font)

        pick_input = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(320, 25))
        pick_input.SetFont(txt_font)

        pick_confirm_but = wx.Button(self, -1, size=(150, 25))
        pick_confirm_but.SetLabel("Confirm")
        pick_confirm_but.SetFont(but_font)

        prog_msg_area_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        prog_msg_area = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "MSG MSG MSG", size=(-1, 25), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        prog_msg_area.SetBackgroundColour("White")
        prog_msg_area.SetFont(txt_font)
        prog_msg_area_sizer.Add(prog_msg_area, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, border=0)


        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_label, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, border=3)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_input, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_confirm_but, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(prog_msg_area_sizer, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        parent.main_sizer.Add(self.panel_sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=15)

        # CHANGED
        self.SetSizer(self.panel_sizer)

wx_app = Wx_app()       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Set the panel sizer as sizer of the panel, main sizer as sizer of frame. Add panel to main sizer better in "MyFrame" constructor (not necessary but more logical) and don't call "Fit".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made the changes you suggested (I think) and now i just see a tiny green square in the top left of the frame. i edited the code to show my changes. could you please be more specific as to why this isnt working thanks.

Comment: The best advice I can give you: USE WXGLADE for wxpython. It fixes your life and you learn a lot of WXPython seeing the clean generated code.

Comment: I oversaw that you added the panel sizer to main sizer. Instead you should add the panel itself to main sizer.

Answer (score 0):

I've never attempted to set the sizer for one class to be the sizer for another, which is what you appear to be doing here.
Set the sizer for the panel and separately for the frame.
See below: you'll note that I've made a copy of the panel to illustrate 2 panels in the frame.

```
import time
import os
import gc
import wx
import wx.grid

# wxpython app
# read ss from files or live version
class Wx_app(wx.App):

    # __init__ gets called first when any class is initialized
    def __init__(self):

    # intiialize the App window
        super().__init__(clearSigInt=True)

        # don't set size of the frame, just position. let
        # sizers do the sizing?
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, pos=(10,10))

# frame class (wx python wind)
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # ini the frame and show it
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # main sizer, will contain all of the other sizers
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # FONTS
        # font to use for the panel in labels, text ctrls, etc
        txt_font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        # font to use for buttons is slightly small than txt_font
        but_font = wx.Font(15, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)

        # PANEL 1
        # first panel is at the top, contains manual pick area plus msg area
        self.pick_area_panel = PickAreaPanel(self, txt_font, but_font)
        self.pick_area_panel2 = PickAreaPanel(self, txt_font, but_font)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.pick_area_panel, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.pick_area_panel2, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.main_sizer)

        # show the frame with panel
        self.Show(True)

# panel class
class PickAreaPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, txt_font, but_font):

        # ini
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        # set background colour for panel
        self.SetBackgroundColour("Green")

        # create the sizer for this panel.
        # stuff is organized horizontally left to right
        self.panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # NOTE: By setting width to -1, we tell to go with sizer, and height to 100
        # sets a fixed height
        pick_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Confirm Pick R1 P1: ", size=(240, 25))
        pick_label.SetBackgroundColour("Red")
        pick_label.SetFont(txt_font)

        # input textctrl for the manual pick
        pick_input = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(320, 25))
        pick_input.SetFont(txt_font)

        # button to confirm manual pick
        pick_confirm_but = wx.Button(self, -1, size=(150, 25))
        pick_confirm_but.SetLabel("Confirm")
        pick_confirm_but.SetFont(but_font)

        # PROG MSG AREA
        # no fixed size, fills rest of panel after previous elements
        # need a nested sizer so can control borders
        # and give it a left borcer thats different from its top border
        prog_msg_area_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        prog_msg_area = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "MSG MSG MSG", size=(-1, 25), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        prog_msg_area.SetBackgroundColour("White")
        prog_msg_area.SetFont(txt_font)
        prog_msg_area_sizer.Add(prog_msg_area, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, border=0)

        # add elements to panel sizer
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_label, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, border=3)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_input, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel_sizer.Add(pick_confirm_but, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # prog msg area has its own horiz sizer so can set a left border diff from top border
        self.panel_sizer.Add(prog_msg_area_sizer)

        # add panel sizer to the main sizer
        # set proporition to 0 so height of panel doesnt change when height of frame changes
        # adds a border around the entire panel
        #parent.main_sizer.Add(self.panel_sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL, border=15)

        # set panel to use the main sizer
        # not sure exactly how this works....
        self.SetSizer(self.panel_sizer)

wx_app = Wx_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

[image]